# Show The first field value based on 2nd field value dynamically?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, app-development

I have create a page which has picklist based on that picklist i have to show the rows and in that rows i have toshow 1st row value based on 2nd valu means

```
 level          low days             high days          level fee
   1              0                   [       ]         [        ]
   2           highdays+1             [       ]         [       ]
```

i want show the low days value based on high value below is my code please let me know.

```
public class dynamicControllerr {

    public dynamicControllerr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

public PageReference AddRecord() {

       //Assign your own data to do this. for testing I just placed the dummy data.

       //Test Data
       lstWrapper= new list<MyWrapper>();
        integer k=Integer.valueOf(selected);
        for(integer i=1;i<=k;i++)
        {
         MyWrapper oWrapp = new MyWrapper();
        oWrapp.sName='Level'+i;
        oWrapp.isFlag= false;
        lstWrapper.add(oWrapp);
        }

        system.debug(selected);
        return null;
    }
public PageReference save() {

        system.debug(lstWrapper);

       //insert lstWrapper;
        return null;
    }

     public list<MyWrapper> lstWrapper {get;set;}

     public list<integer> lststrings {get;set;}
      public string selected{get;set;}



     public dynamicControllerr(){
        this.lstWrapper = new list<MyWrapper>(); 
        MyWrapper oWrapp = new MyWrapper();
        oWrapp.sName='Level'+1;
        oWrapp.isFlag= true;
        lstWrapper.add(oWrapp);

         selected='1';    
     }
      public class MyWrapper{
          public string sName{ get;set;}
          public boolean isFlag{get;set;}
      }

}
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="BucketRate__c" extensions="dynamicController">

   <apex:form >


    <apex:pageblock >
    <apex:commandButton value=" Save " action="{!save}" reRender="pb1"/>
    <br></br><br></br>

   <apex:outputText value="Bucket Rate Level"></apex:outputText>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!selected}" size="1" >
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="6" itemLabel="6"/>
             <apex:selectOption itemValue="7" itemLabel="7"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="8" itemLabel="8"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemValue="9" itemLabel="9"/>

        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!AddRecord}"  reRender="pb1"/>
   </apex:selectList>
             <br></br>
            <br></br>
      <!-- <apex:commandButton value=" Add Row " action="{!AddRecord}" reRender="pb1"/>-->

        <br></br>
            <br></br>          
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="pb1" value="{!lstWrapper}"  var="item">
                <apex:column headerValue="Level">
                    <apex:outputlabel value="{!item.sName}" />

                   <!-- {!BucketRate__c.Bucket_Rate_Levels__c}-->
                </apex:column>
                 <apex:column headerValue="Low Days">
                 <!--<apex:inputText value="{!item.isFlag}" />-->

          <!--<apex:outputlabel value="{!item.ldays}" />-->
                 <apex:outputText >0</apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="High Days">
                 <!--<apex:inputText value="{!item.isFlag}" />-->
                 <apex:inputText value="{!BucketRate__c.High_Days__c}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Level Fee">
                 <!--<apex:inputText value="{!item.isFlag}" />-->
                 <apex:inputText value="{!BucketRate__c.Level_Fee__c}" />
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>           
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!AddRecord}" name="methodOneInJavascript" rerender="pb1"/>


     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```